# Calcular o final do ecrã

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Bom, tenho um **botão** que abre uma **div**.

Se este **botão** estiver no meio do **ecrã**, então abro a **div** abaixo do **botão**.

Caso o **botão** esteja o final do **ecrã** e ao abrir a **div** não dê para ver seu conteúdo, então abro a **div** abaixo do **botão**.

Mas, como **calcular** se o **botão** está no **final do ecrã**?

Vejam bem: **NÃO** É no **final da página**, mas **SIM** no **final da parte visível da pagina**.

Comment: Depende do que vc chama "final do ecrã"... para fazer esse cálculo, vc precisa definir o que considera "o botão no final do ecrã", pois o botão pode estar EXATAMENTE no final ou alguns pixels acima.

Comment: @Dcdsam, primeiramente, novamente obrigado pela força. Então, à media que você vai rolando a tela para cima, o botão vai descendo, lógico. E, quando o botão chegar no final da tela, não no final da página pois uma página só termina no final do html, mas no final da parte visível da tela, então tenho a posição que desejo calcular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código verifica se o elemento (no caso, um botão) está no final da área visível da tela ou abaixo dela:

```
$(window).on("scroll load", function(){
    dist_bot_top = $("#botao").offset().top; // distância do botão para o início do documento
    janela_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // distância que a página foi rolada
    altura_bot = $("#botao").outerHeight(); // altura real do botão
    // Abaixo subtraio a distância do botão para o início do documento
    // pela distância que a página foi rolada (isso me dá a distância
    // real do botão até o topo da área visível da janela) e comparo
    // se é igual ou maior que a área visível da janela: window.innerHeight
    if((dist_bot_top-janela_scroll)+altura_bot >= window.innerHeight){
        console.log("Botão está no final");
    }
    // este "else" é apenas para apagar o console, pode deletar
    else{
        console.clear();
    }
});
```

```js
$(window).on("scroll load", function(){
 dist_bot_top = $("#botao").offset().top; // distância do botão para o início do documento
 janela_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // distância que a página foi rolada
 altura_bot = $("#botao").outerHeight(); // altura real do botão
 // Abaixo subtraio a distância do botão para o início do documento
 // pela distância que a página foi rolada (isso me dá a distância
 // real do botão até o topo da área visível da janela) e comparo
 // se é igual ou maior que a área visível da janela: window.innerHeight
 if((dist_bot_top-janela_scroll)+altura_bot >= window.innerHeight){
  console.log("Botão está no final");
 }
 // este "else" é apenas para apagar o console, pode deletar
 else{
  console.clear();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role para baixo
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<input id="botao" type="button" value="ok" />

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, adaptando aqui ficou como abaixo.

Mas será que tem uma forma de otimizar esse código?

Estou achando que não está bem escrito, embora esteja funcionando corretamente.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // entrega o primeiro elemento da select option à div .selecionada
    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(".selectOptions select > option:first-child").html());

    /*popula as li's*/
    $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
        //Não exibe a primeira li pois esta já está sendo exibida na .selecionada
        if ($(this).is(':first-child')) $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li value='" + this.value + "' style='display:none;'>" + this.text + "</li>");
        else $(".selectOptions ul").append("<li style='display:block;' value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</li>");
    });

    //contador de vezes que abre e fecha a ul
    contador = 0;

    $(".selectOptions .selecionada").click(function(e) {

        quantasLis = $(".selectOptions ul li").length;

        if (contador % 2 == 0) {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("display", "block");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").css("display", "none").slideDown(400);

            if (quantasLis > 4) {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', '175px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            } else {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css('height', (quantasLis*35)+'px');
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "auto");
            }


            janela = $(window).height();

            selecionadaPosicao = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").offset().top;
            selecionadaAltura = $(".selectOptions .selecionada").height();
            ulAltura = $(".selectOptions ul").height();
            janelaScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // distância que a página foi rolada

            posicaoFinal = ulAltura + $(".selectOptions .selecionada").outerHeight();

            total = selecionadaPosicao + selecionadaAltura + ulAltura - janelaScroll;

            if (total >= janela)
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", posicaoFinal, "important");
            else             
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("bottom", "0", "important");


        } else {

            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
            $(".selectOptions ul li").slideUp(400, function() {
                $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
            });
        }

        contador++;

        e.stopPropagation();

    });

    /*ai clicar na li, busca correspondência na select option e o checa (marca)*/
    $('.selectOptions ul li').on('click', function(evt) {
        /*Joga a li selecionada na label .selecionada*/
        $(".selectOptions .selecionada").html($(this).html());
        /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
        $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this));
        // Armazena nome do maos que quer selecionar
        var li = $(this).attr("value");
        // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
        // options possÃ­veis
        var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
            // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
            return $(this).attr('value') === li;
        });
        // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
        opcao.attr('selected', true);

    });

    // ao clicar em qualquer coissa, fecha a ul caso ela esteja aberta
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "auto" ||
            $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow-y") == "scroll") {
            $(".selectOptions .selecionada").trigger("click");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: verdade, vou remover essa parte.